# obtener id de string html con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente string html:

```
var cadena = "<div id = 'div1'><div id = 'divImg'></div><div>"
```

necesito obtener por jquery el id del div padre, o del primer div, pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es extraer el id del string te recomendaría realizar un split de la cadena en cada `<id=>` y con ello tendrías una lista con todos los posibles id, luego has otro split en `<'>` y con esto tendrás el primer id en una posición de la lista solo luego con un console.log visualiza la lista y saca el id que quieres de la posición de la lista.

```
var cadena = "<div id = 'div1'><div id = 'divImg'></div><div>"
var listC = cadena.split('id =');
var listID = listC[1].split("'");
var IDEnd = listID[1];
console.log(IDEnd);
```

Otra solución en javaScript seria:

```
var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(cadena);
var firstId = frag.firstElementChild;
console.log(firstId.id);
```

Y así sucesivamente pueden ir apareciendo más.
Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo he entendido bien lo que quieres es esto:

```
$("#divImg").parent().prop("id")
```

Entiendo que tu estas trabajando desde el id del divImg

Editado despues de leer tu comentario, no es necesario hacer ningún tipo de split como comentan con jquery te permite recoger el valor.

```
$("<div id = 'div1'><div id = 'divImg'></div><div>").prop("id")
```

Comment: De hecho obtengo asi tal cual el html en la variable cadena, y necesito el id del primer elemento, seria el id div1